# Solar analog watch be worn on Shabbos where in the dark the second stops?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology

Can a solar charge watch that the second hand stops moving in the dark after 30 minutes to save power and resumes operation when brought back in the light, be worn on Shaboss?

Comment: can you put a link to a product description?

Comment: what's the point of a second hand which doesn't tell seconds accurately? (i assume the minute and hour hands keep moving in the dark) sounds like a psik reishei delo ichpat lei

Comment: Which Malacha do you think is being violated?

Answer (score 1):

A regular solar/light powered watch (as well as an automatic watch [powered by the movement of the wrist]) is allowed on Shabbat, even though one would put it in the dark and take it out again, which would start/stop the charging process...why would the movement of the second hand change anything?